# AWS S3: private access using id_token from Cognito like to the ApiGateway: is it possible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I successfully setup access to the Lambda using `token_id` from Cognito - client adds header `Authorization: <token_id>` and Api Gateway validate this token. I hope that I can setup similar access to the S3 from the client browser. For that I wrote policy for the S3 bucket (every user has its own directory for files):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::buc/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried this call:

`curl -v --header 'Authorization: [id_token_from_cognito_after_signup]' https://s3.amazonaws.com/buc/<sub>/myfile.jpg`

That return 400 `Authorization header is invalid -- one and only one ' ' (space) required`. On the web I found that this error can be unrelated to the spaces - because this request has the correct amount of spaces (I tried request without spaces too).

It is interesting that in the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/S3_Authentication2.html) about S3 is not mentioned Cognito.

I do not want to use js sdk on the client for speed and simplicity.

Comment: I'm reasonably sure that you need to use the cognito credentials to create a signed request for S3 -- not send the token directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were able to access your API using the cognito token because of the integration of cognito in API Gateway as it is fully described in [aws blog](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/compute/authorizing-access-through-a-proxy-resource-to-amazon-api-gateway-and-aws-lambda-using-amazon-cognito-user-pools/)

> The Cognito user pools integration with API Gateway provides a new way
>   to secure your API workloads

However, as of today, there's no such possibility for S3. You would need to compute the signature yourself as it was explained in the doc you reference. (various examples are referenced [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-developer-guide/RESTAuthentication.html))

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this policy mentioned [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_s3_cognito-bucket.html)

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::<BUCKET-NAME>"],
      "Condition": {"StringLike": {"s3:prefix": ["cognito/<APPLICATION-NAME>/"]}}
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:DeleteObject"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::<BUCKET-NAME>/cognito/<APPLICATION-NAME>/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}",
        "arn:aws:s3:::<BUCKET-NAME>/cognito/<APPLICATION-NAME>/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hm, I think that in principle this is like my current policy - this one only with added condition and permission for delete and put. Also interesting that this policy example from documentation cannot be saved in the bucket preferences due to the `Missing required field Principal`.